# JSONata: How to get all paths from the payload?

Tags: json-query, jsonata

How to get all the paths of the input object and traverse it according to my wish.

One such use case is I want to convert the value of all except few fields/nested fields in a object to uppercase.

For example, assume below is the input,

```json
{
  "name": "John",
    "age": 30,
    "bio": "I am a software developer.",
    "username": "john_doe",
    "profiles": [
        {
            "network": "Twitter",
            "username": "john_doe"
        },
        {
            "network": "Facebook",
            "username": "john_doe"
        }
    ]
}
```

For the above payload, I want to convert all values to uppercase, except for `$.username` and `$.profiles.username`. In this case, I would know only which are those fields to except, not the paths to convert.

Output for above would be,

```json
{
  "name": "JOHN",
    "age": 30,
    "bio": "I AM A SOFTWARE DEVELOPER.",
    "username": "john_doe",
    "profiles": [
        {
            "network": "TWITTER",
            "username": "john_doe"
        },
        {
            "network": "FACEBOOK",
            "username": "john_doe"
        }
    ]
}
```

How to achieve this using JSONata ?

Answer (score 0):

You can write a recursive function to dig deep into your object and then replace values that match your criteria:

```
(
  $recurse := function($object) {
    (
      $type($object) = "object"
        ? $merge($each($object, function($value, $key) { 
            { 
              $key: $type($value) = "string" and $key != "username"
                ? $uppercase($value)
                : $recurse($value)
            } 
          }))
        : $type($object) = "array"
          ? $map($object, $recurse)
          : $object
    )
  };

  $recurse($)
)
```

Check it out on the Stedi playground: https://stedi.link/HYL5ebO

Comment: I appreciate your answer, but my point isn't exactly on how to convert into lowercase, but my point is how to traverse through all paths and exclude few. For example, using JSONPath, we get all paths of the object and exclude the paths we want to ignore. Like that, how to get all paths.

Comment: your solution works for the above scenario, but we need solution based on path, for example, in above solution it excludes username in root level and profile level also. Assume the exclude list has only "profiles.*.username", then the code needs to be updated. We want a dynamic solution based on the paths, not to modify the code.

Comment: You can build the list of all possible paths by traversing your object using a recursive function and passing in the parent path as an argument like this:

https://stedi.link/MXEP8yX

Comment: However, it's not straightforward to modify your object based on the list of paths like that, and I would recommend uppercasing keys by a preset list of paths during the initial traversal, similar to my original answer: https://stedi.link/fUFYhkp